# NDK includes and the Android Gradle plugin version 0.7.+

Tags: android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Version 0.7.+'s of the gradle plugin includes preliminary ndk support. I worked off [the examples](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/2e1f7810edd76d92cee8d3e06bc4dec0c288adea/tests/ndkSanAngeles/build.gradle) but I get a compilation error when trying to include a standard NDK header:

```
In file included from /foo/src/main/jni/Bar.h:4:0,
                 from /foo/src/main/jni/Bar.cpp:1:
/foo/src/main/jni/baz.h:4:25: fatal error: android/log.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Where `baz.h` has this line:

```
#include <android/log.h>
```

And my gradle file has:

```
ndk {
  ldLibs "log"
}
```

Has anyone made this work?

Comment: The error is a compilation error, not a linking error, so fixing it would require a `-I` flag. Have you tried using `cFlags "-I/path/"`?

Comment: But which path? android/log.h is a standard NDK header, and I don't want to hard-code an arbitrary NDK install path. When building without gradle, this path is added automatically correctly.

Comment: The gradle plugin creates an Android.mk somewhere in the project. Have you checked if anything is missing from the generated file? It's strange that in any case the NDK includes don't get included by default..

Comment: Yeah, I checked it. It wasn't clear that anything was wrong with it. Very strange.

Comment: You could disable the ndk compilation with `android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variantData.ndkCompileTask.enabled = false
}`. You will have to set the NDK_OUT so the compiled .so are in build/ndk/debug/lib/<arch>/, but they will be included in your apk nicely.

Comment: I meant NDK_LIBS_OUT, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be `ldLibs "-llog"` ?

P.S.
NDK support is very unstable now... I was fighting with it for a few days - it completely broken on Windows. No easy way to disable it (but still possible). On some circumstances build process will generate wrong file path (like /foo/bar//foo/bar/source.c). So we switched back to the 0.6.+ version and monitoring https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?q=tools%40android.com

Comment: AFAIK it's `ldLibs "log"`, also check the samples. There is a nice way to disable it that Xavier suggested: `android { sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/nojni'] }` (from here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/Lwo2oF2mq5g)